# Installing SQL server service, account to use

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm in the following situation(With SQL 2008 Express):

[image: SQL Server 2008 install]

It says "Microsoft recommends that you use a separate account for each SQL Server service."

Okay. This is my local machine I'll be developing on, so I think I'll only need one instance.

The problem comes with the "account name" linked to the SQL Server Database Engine(the top one).

The field is clickable. Normally, both fields are blank. I picked system, but I'm not sure what effects this might have. I tried using my own username and password, but that was rejected. That last part is what worries me most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Express, Local System will be fine for the service and browser.